# Wretch addon modules not found for import in React app on Node 14.15.1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, import

We have a React app running on node `14.15.1` and I'm in the process of upgrading dependencies. I've upgraded the `wretch` (https://github.com/elbywan/wretch) dependency to `wretch@2` which requires import of it's addon modules, e.g `import QueryStringAddon from 'wretch/addons/queryString'` however my app now no longer compiles with the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'wretch/addons/queryString' in 'C:\Users\path\to\my\component'
```

I'm using VSCode and it recognizes the module import including giving tooltip support, and I've confirmed the files are in the expected `node_modules` folder. Additionally if I change my import to a relative import into `node_modules` from my current file (e.g. `import QueryStringAddon from '../../../node_modules/wretch/dist/addons/queryString'`) then that does compile.

I'm looking for a diagnosis of why my import is not successful, and what I can do to import the addons successfully.

*Edit #1*:

I believe the underlying issue is having a `/` in the path I'm importing from as after further investigation I don't believe we have any other imports of the form `module/sub_module` and doing `import { queryStringAddon } from 'wretch/addons'` similarly fails.

*Edit #2*:

I've now run the app starting up with the `traceResolution` option set to `true` in my `tsconfig.json`, it resulted in the following relevant section of the output:

```
======== Resolving module 'wretch/addons' from 'C:/Users/jake/path/to/my-app/src/components/ApiResource/index.tsx'. ========
Explicitly specified module resolution kind: 'NodeJs'.
Loading module 'wretch/addons' from 'node_modules' folder, target file type 'TypeScript'.
Directory 'C:/Users/jake/path/to/my-app/src/components/ApiResource/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory 'C:/Users/jake/path/to/my-app/src/components/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory 'C:/Users/jake/path/to/my-app/src/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Found 'package.json' at 'C:/Users/jake/path/to/my-app/node_modules/wretch/package.json'.
'package.json' has a 'typesVersions' field with version-specific path mappings.
'package.json' has a 'typesVersions' entry '*' that matches compiler version '3.8.3', looking for a pattern to match module name 'addons'.
Module name 'addons', matched pattern '*'.
Trying substitution 'dist/*', candidate module location: 'dist/addons'.
File 'C:/Users/jake/path/to/my-app/node_modules/wretch/dist/addons.ts' does not exist.
File 'C:/Users/jake/path/to/my-app/node_modules/wretch/dist/addons.tsx' does not exist.
File 'C:/Users/jake/path/to/my-app/node_modules/wretch/dist/addons.d.ts' does not exist.
'package.json' does not have a 'typings' field.
'package.json' has 'types' field './dist/index.d.ts' that references 'C:/Users/jake/path/to/my-app/node_modules/wretch/dist/addons/dist/index.d.ts'.
'package.json' has a 'typesVersions' entry '*' that matches compiler version '3.8.3', looking for a pattern to match module name 'dist/index.d.ts'.
Module name 'dist/index.d.ts', matched pattern '*'.
Trying substitution 'dist/*', candidate module location: 'dist/dist/index.d.ts'.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location 'C:/Users/jake/path/to/my-app/node_modules/wretch/dist/addons/dist/dist/index.d.ts', target file type 'TypeScript'.
Trying substitution 'dist/*/index.d.ts', candidate module location: 'dist/dist/index.d.ts/index.d.ts'.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location 'C:/Users/jake/path/to/my-app/node_modules/wretch/dist/addons/dist/dist/index.d.ts/index.d.ts', target file type 'TypeScript'.
Trying substitution 'dist/index.d.ts', candidate module location: 'dist/index.d.ts'.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location 'C:/Users/jake/path/to/my-app/node_modules/wretch/dist/addons/dist/index.d.ts', target file type 'TypeScript'.
Trying substitution 'dist/*/index.d.ts', candidate module location: 'dist/addons/index.d.ts'.
File 'C:/Users/jake/path/to/my-app/node_modules/wretch/dist/addons/index.d.ts' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
Resolving real path for 'C:/Users/jake/path/to/my-app/node_modules/wretch/dist/addons/index.d.ts', result 'C:/Users/jake/path/to/my-app/node_modules/wretch/dist/addons/index.d.ts'.
======== Module name 'wretch/addons' was successfully resolved to 'C:/Users/jake/path/to/my-app/node_modules/wretch/dist/addons/index.d.ts'. ========
```

So from that it looks like typescript is able to resolve it, but it's not being found when it's running.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to the fact that wretch v2 uses the exports fields in its [package.json](https://github.com/elbywan/wretch/blob/master/package.json). The exports field is supported starting from react-scripts v5 (which uses webpack 5). So you can either upgrade react-scripts or change your import to the real path `import QueryStringAddon from "wretch/dist/addons/queryString";`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in one of my projects for the `FormDataAddon`; what is did to ignore the error is create a mock like this:

[image: source]

and in the `formData.js` i added:

```
   export default jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {});
```

This is what worked for me altleast, I hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can specify in `webpack.config`:

```
alias: {
  "wretch": "wretch/dist"
}
```

In such case import from `'wretch/addons/queryString'` will work correctly both for runtime and typings.